# Jquery if $(window) scroll down function

Tags: jquery

hello I need when `$(window)` is scrolled down with `100%` alert something
how can I do it?

Comment: You mean when window reach the bottom alert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("END!");
   }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52jrnytu/)

Comment: why it is not working, what browser you use? can you post code which you tried?

Comment: @valkharitonashvili What do you mean not working? Message is not alerted at all?

Comment: Does window and document keywords belong to WebAPI or HTML or Jquery?

Answer (score 4):

I used something like this once :)

```
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
                       //alert
}
```

Just play with the numbers, this one is built to pop out the alert just almost before the end of the scroll

Comment: as explained, this one shows alert 50px before the end of the page. 
I pasted it here because I find it very useful in a lot of things, and it uses the consept of the main question here. 

I used it when developing a blog with a "load more posts" button automatically when it scrolls almost to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Does window and document keywords belong to WebAPI or HTML or Jquery?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one,
When you scroll the page and if the page is reached to bottom, then alert message will get displayed.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("Bottom Reached!");
   }
});
```