# Style your navigation bar when scrolled 100px from top

Tags: jquery, navigation, height, navbar

**Hi,**

If you take a look at this page > http://www.wikihow.com/
You'll notice the navigation bar height will be less greater when scrolled down. I want to apply this to my navigation bar using jQuery. I've found solutions on google, but people say you'll need some plugins. I think this isn't true, am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: If you already use jQuery this should be managable without any other plugins

Comment: Correct, you can do this without plugins. A combination of `.scrol()` and `.scrollTop()` should be a good hint to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = 0;

   if (typeof window.pageYOffset !== 'undefined' ) {
      scroll = window.pageYOffset;
   }

   var d = document.documentElement;
   if (d.clientHeight) {
       scroll = d.scrollTop;
   }
   scroll = document.body.scrollTop;

   if (scroll > 100) {
      // scroll greater than 100px, decrease navigation bar height
   }else{
      // scroll less than 100px,  increase navigation bar height
   }
});
```

Also, You need to make navigation bar **position:fixed**

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

View my comment in this post, might be useful: [Jquery if $(window) scroll down function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399606/jquery-if-window-scroll-down-function/25399715#25399715)

and to keep the div of the navigation bar on the top when scrolling you should define it

```
position: fixed;
```